# Unable to use key file "C:\GIT\HOME\.ssh\id_rsa" (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key (new format))

Tags: ssh, gitlab, openssh, ssh-keygen

I'm trying to make a GitClone from a Gitlab repository. I have generated a ssh key with the command ssh-keygen on my cmd:
[image]

Then i added my pub key (starting with ssh_rsa) to my Gitlab account, but whenever i try to make a gitclone, i have the following error:
[image]

Any advices? I tried to convert my key with puttygen, but still doesn't work!
The start of my pub key is ssh-rsa key..
And the private key: --BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY--
..key..
--END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY--

Output of ssh -v git@gitlab.(..).com
[image]

Comment: Can you try with `ssh -v git@gitlab.com`? This will give you the info about what happens with SSH.

Comment: @SimonDoppler i updated the post with the output of the command, i cannot really understand why i'm getting kicked out.

Comment: Getting kicked out is normal, I just wanted to check if SSH works (it does, since the Gitlab server tell you *Welcome to Gitlab* and recognises you). I don't see the path of the public key (it should the line above the first in your screenshot). Is this path the same as the one which fails with git ?

Comment: Actually the path of my public key is c:\Users\%username%\.ssh\id_rsa. But i created a new folder c:\GIT\HOME\.ssh\id_rsa where i copy-paste the keys. And i added this last path to git.

Answer (score 0):

OK. i Solved the problem. Since i was using TortoiseGit to make a GitClone, this last one doesn't accepts Openssh key. Therefore, once you generate the key, you need to convert it in putty format with Puttygen. Moreover, you must pay attention to the version of the new generated key and you can change the version on puttygen on key>parameters to save key!